# OC Crash:return NSMutableString as NSString to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, assembly

build in release mode and run,then crash.

```
- (NSString *)testMutableStringReturnStringCrash{
    NSString *str = nil;

    if(str.length <= 0){
        str = mutableStringAsNSString();
    }else{
        str = @"1";
    }

    str = str.length > 0 ? str : @"2";
    str = str.length > 0 ? str : @"3";

    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
    return content;
}


NSString *mutableStringAsNSString(){
    return [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"0"];
}
```

I have found that is a question about the code's assembly language. （Released twice）
But I don't understand why.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is the real purpose of this code?

Comment: how do you know that is that code the origin of the crash?, for me there is not crash at all

Comment: The crash occurred in the project file.I just extracted the part of crashed code.

Comment: Have you set Build Configuration Release

Comment: can you provide the resimbolicated crash log?

Comment: How do you know it's the very same object instance being `objc_release`d marked by you in red?

Answer (score 0):

when you set str = str.length > 0 ? str : @"2",the str is be __NSCFString not muti, so you reset str make crash

Comment: I don't think so.
The crash was because it was released twice.